# Reflexive Banach Space: For any $x ∈ E$, there exists $x_0 ∈ M$ so that $|x−x_0| =\inf\{|x−y| :y ∈ M \}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be a reflexive $ \mathbb K$−Banach space and assume that $M$ is a convex, closed, bounded subset of $E.$ Prove that for any $x ∈ E$, there exists $x_0 ∈ M$ so that $|x−x_0| = \inf\{|x−y| :y ∈ M \}$.

I got the hint to use [Fenchel-Rockafellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel's_duality_theorem) Theorem (also known as Fenchel's Duality Theorem) and then use the weak* topology $\sigma(E^*,E)$.

But I don't see the use of applying this theorem in this case. Why does one need this and how does one prove this statement using this particular theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the classical result in convex analysis. You do not actually need Fenchel duality here if you combine the following three basic facts:

- [Any closed convex bounded set is weakly compact in a reflexive Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834236/any-closed-convex-bounded-set-is-weakly-compact-in-a-reflexive-banach-space)
- [Norm is weakly lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470217/norm-is-weakly-lower-semicontinuous)
- [Weierstrass extreme value theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868810/application-of-a-general-weierstrass-theorem)

P.S. The set does not have to be bounded if you use the third mentioned variant of the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: I find it simpler to look at $$\bigcap_{r > \operatorname{dist}(x,M)} (\overline{B_r(x)}\cap M).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, it is *exactly* as the standard proof goes there.

Comment: But I don't use the lower semicontinuity of the norm or the Weierstraß theorem, just (weak) compactness.

Comment: @DanielFischer You suggest to prove the Weierstraß theorem instead of refering to it? Because the way it is proved is precisely looking at those sets and then take the cluster point as $x_0$. My point was to leave some details to OP to discover.

Comment: Okay, thinking about it, it's the same proof as for the extreme value theorem.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for the hint. But from the 2nd point, how can one get that $|x-x_0|=inf\{|x-y| : y \in M\}$? Since they use there $liminf$ and not the infimum? And what role does the Weierstrass Theorem play here? I don't see the connection here.

Comment: @TigerLa $\liminf$ is used in the 2d point to prove the weak lower semicontinuity of a norm [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition). Weierstrass theorem is used in the 3d point to conclude the existence of $x_0$.

Comment: Okay, I will try to solve it with these 3 points. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TigerLa The basic idea is that 1 gives compact, 2 gives continuous and 3 gives compact+continuous=minimum exists (Weierstrass).